# Construction of Inverse Image Functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and $\varphi:X\to Y$ a continuous map. Let $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ be the categories corresponding to the open sets of $X$ and $Y$ with arrows given by reverse inclusion. Then a presheaf on $X$ is a functor $\mathcal{F}:\mathbf{X}\to\mathbf{Set}$, and the category $\mathbf{PShv}(\mathbf{X})$ of presheaves on $X$ is just the functor category $\mathbf{Set}^\mathbf{X}$.

We obtain a functor $\Phi:\mathbf{Y}\to\mathbf{X}$ by setting $\Phi(U)=\varphi^{-1}(U)$. Then the direct image functor $I:\mathbf{PShv}(\mathbf{X})\to\mathbf{PShv}(\mathbf{Y})$ is given by setting $I(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{F}\circ\Phi$.

However I can't seem to give such a clean construction of the inverse image functor $J:\mathbf{PShv}(\mathbf{Y})\to\mathbf{PShv}(\mathbf{X})$. I know that for a presheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $Y$ and an open $U\subseteq X$ we set $$\varphi^{-1}\mathcal{G}(U)=\mathop{\lim_{\longrightarrow}}_{V\supseteq\varphi(U)}\mathcal{G}(V)$$
I was hoping to find a more "categorical" description though, since, at least to me, the functoriality of $J$ is not obvious from this in the same way that it is with $I$. I know that $J$ is the left adjoint of $I$, so I feel like there should be another construction which makes this clearer.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_image_functor) that the functoriality follows from the universal property of colimits. I think the colimit is taken over the images under $\mathcal{G}$ of the $V\subseteq Y$ such that there is an arrow $\Phi(V)\to U$ in $\mathbf{X}$, but I'm struggling to see how this shows $J$ is a functor.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I just realized: $\mathcal F \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} \mathcal G$.

You basically want to construct a morphism $\Gamma(V, \varphi^{-1} \mathcal F) = \varinjlim_\limits{U \supseteq \varphi(V)} \Gamma(U,\mathcal F) \to \varinjlim_\limits{U' \supseteq \varphi(V')}\Gamma(U', \mathcal F) = \Gamma(V', \varphi^{-1}\mathcal F)$ for any inclusion $V' \subseteq V$ of open subsets.

Now the universal property of the colimit used to compute $\Gamma(V,\varphi^{-1}\mathcal F)$ tells you how to obtain morphism starting at $\Gamma(V,\varphi^{-1}\mathcal F)$.

Namely: You have to give a morphism $\Gamma(U,\mathcal F) \to \varinjlim_\limits{U' \supseteq \varphi(V')}\Gamma(U', \mathcal F) = \Gamma(V', \varphi^{-1}\mathcal F)$ for any open $U \supseteq \varphi(V)$ compatible with the transition maps (which are of course given via restriction).

Now just note that since $V' \subseteq V$ one certainly has $U \supseteq \varphi(V) \supseteq \varphi(V')$ so that $\Gamma(U,\mathcal F)$ is a part of the second colimit, i.e. comes with a canonical map into $\Gamma(U,\mathcal F) \to \Gamma(V',\varphi^{-1}\mathcal F)$ as desired.

Then you have to check that these maps are compatible with restrictions so that they induce the desired morphism $\Gamma(V,\varphi^{-1}\mathcal F) \to \Gamma(V', \varphi^{-1} \mathcal F)$.

$\textit{Uniqueness}$ of the morphism induced on the colimit then tells you that this construction behaves well with respect to inclusions $V'' \subseteq V' \subseteq V$, i.e. is functorial.

Comment: Ah just in case you haven't yet seen the notation: $\Gamma(U,\mathcal F) \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} \mathcal F(U)$.

Comment: Also regarding the "naturality" of this construction: Think of the colimit as "We try to find a "smallest" open environment in $Y$ containing $\varphi(U)$. This will not always be possible though (if it is, the colimit will "degenerate" and just be the value of sections on this minimal open subset though!).

Comment: So instead we are taking all sections above some open subset containing $\varphi(U)$ into account and identify two such sections if they coincide on a smaller open subset still containing $\varphi(U)$. So this will result in the kind of "best approximation from the outside" of $\varphi(U)$ by sections over open sets.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation, this has definitely helped me to see how universal properties come into this. I think maybe I should have been clearer, but when I mentioned functoriality, I meant as a functor between the presheaf categories, so that if we have a morphism $N:\mathcal{G}_1\to\mathcal{G_2}$ in $\mathbf{PShv}(\mathbf{Y})$ (which I think is just a natural transformation of the functors), then we have a map $\varphi^{-1}N:\varphi^{-1}\mathcal{G}_1\to\varphi^{-1}\mathcal{G}_2$...

Comment: ... and that these behave well under composition etc. Maybe I misinterpreted the Wikipedia article, but is this also a consequence of the universal property?

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood your question then.
The same way of thinking applies to this problem though:
$\Gamma(V,\varphi^{-1}\mathcal G_1) \to \Gamma(V,\varphi^{-1} \mathcal G_2)$ is given as $\varinjlim_\limits{U \supseteq \varphi(V)}(N_{U} : \Gamma(U, \mathcal G_1) \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal G_2) )$.
This is well-defined because $N$ behaves well with respect to restriction, which are the transition maps used in the colimit.

Also: Yes, a morphism of presheaves is the same thing as a natural transformation between the functors.

Comment: Yes, the universal property should also tell you that this construction is functorial. You have to check that both "colimit maps" you'll have to write down. One way to see this is to check that they agree when being precomposed with the canonical inclusions into the colimit corresponding to $\varphi^{-1}(M \circ N)$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks again!